# Turn SQL query which contains multiple join, left join, group by and having to EF core

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this SQL query which is really complex to me and I tried to  convert it to EntityFramework Core code based, but I couldn't do at least the multiple join.

```
SELECT vrCore_Product.iMasterId, vrCore_Product.sName[Particular], 
                            SUM(tCore_Indta_0.fQuantityInBase) - ISNULL(AVG(tCore_ReservedStock_0.fQuantity),0)[Net Quantity],vrPos_Outlet.iMasterId[Product]
                            ,vrCore_Product.sCode[vrCore_Product.sCode0] FROM tCore_Data_0
                            JOIN tCore_Header_0 ON tCore_Header_0.iHeaderId = tCore_Data_0.iHeaderId
                            JOIN tCore_Indta_0 ON tCore_Data_0.iBodyId = tCore_Indta_0.iBodyId
                            JOIN cCore_Vouchers_0 WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ON tCore_Header_0.iVoucherType = cCore_Vouchers_0.iVoucherType
                            JOIN vrCore_Product ON vrCore_Product.iMasterId = tCore_Indta_0.iProduct AND vrCore_Product.iTreeId = 0
                            JOIN vrPos_Outlet ON vrPos_Outlet.iMasterId = tCore_Data_0.iInvTag
                            LEFT JOIN 
                            (
                                Select iProduct, tCore_Data_0.iInvTag, SUM(case bReserveOrRelease when 0 then  tCore_ReservedStock_0.fQuantity else -tCore_ReservedStock_0.fQuantity end) fQuantity 
                                FROM tCore_ReservedStock_0 
                                JOIN tCore_Data_0 ON tCore_Data_0.iTransactionId = tCore_ReservedStock_0.iTransactionId 
                                JOIN tCore_Indta_0 ON tCore_Indta_0.iBodyId = tCore_Data_0.iBodyId
                                JOIN tCore_Header_0 ON tCore_Header_0.iHeaderId = tCore_Data_0.iHeaderId
                                WHERE tCore_Header_0.bSuspended = 0
                                GROUP BY iProduct,tCore_Data_0.iInvTag
                                HAVING SUM(CASE bReserveOrRelease WHEN 0 THEN tCore_ReservedStock_0.fQuantity ELSE -tCore_ReservedStock_0.fQuantity END)<>0
                            )tCore_ReservedStock_0 ON tCore_ReservedStock_0.iProduct = tCore_Indta_0.iProduct AND tCore_ReservedStock_0.iInvTag = tCore_Data_0.iInvTag WHERE tCore_Header_0.bUpdateStocks = 1 AND tCore_Data_0.bSuspendUpdateStocks <> 1 
                         AND tCore_Header_0.bSuspended = 0 AND tCore_Data_0.iAuthStatus < 2 
                         AND (tCore_Header_0.iDate BETWEEN dbo.DateToInt('2020-01-10') AND dbo.DateToInt('2020-01-22') OR (tCore_Header_0.iDate < dbo.DateToInt('2020-01-22') AND tCore_Header_0.iVoucherClass = 512))  AND vrCore_Product.iProductType <> 'Service' AND vrPos_Outlet.iMasterId IN (26) GROUP BY vrPos_Outlet.iMasterId, vrCore_Product.iMasterId, vrCore_Product.sName ,vrCore_Product.sCode HAVING SUM(tCore_Indta_0.fQuantity) <> 0 ORDER BY vrPos_Outlet.iMasterId
```

Answer (score 2):

We think in objects when we code in C#. We think relational when we do T-SQL. This creates a problem called object-relational impedance mismatch. EF helps break that problem by allowing us to think only in objects. You are trying to do the exact opposite, which is translate a query back to an object representation, via a Linq query. Here's a tip: I never do that. My starting point is the C# object model and I model the query thinking in Linq. I don't care about T-SQL.

This might seem like just a matter of syntax, since both T-SQL and Linq are query languages, and in the end, Linq gets translated to T-SQL by EF. However, the difference between them is not only syntax, but the way we think. For instance, while we think about joins in T-SQL, in linq, we think about navigation properties. On one, we think about relations and foreign keys, on the other, we think about objects and graphs.

In the very rare case where I'm better off with a T-SQL query, I rather execute a raw query instead of going through the pain of translating it back to Linq: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

In your case I would do either of the following 2 things:

- I would either simply throw away the T-SQL query and start over, thinking in Linq. It helps if I have a good understanding of the business domain and what I need to extract using that query. This is most of the time, favourite approach.
- Or, in case I'm too committed to the query (pun not intended), I would simply execute it as a raw query using EF (always using parameters instead of concatenating the query with input values, in order to prevent any Sql Injection vulnerability). The only downside to this that your code stops being database engine independent the moment you add a raw query to it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have relationships, you just can use Include() like

```
var data = _context.TcoreData0
                   .Include(x => x.TcoreHeader0)
                   .Include(x => x.TcoreIndta0)
                   .Include("tCore_Header_0.cCore_Vouchers_0")
                   .Include...
```